# Pair each list element with unique combination of state

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn a bit of python 3 with something that i thought was trivial, but is actually winding me up a bit..

i have two lists..

```
items=['a','b','c']
states=[0, 1, -1]
```

and i want to generate all unique combinations of ***state***, that those items can have... so for this example it would start as..

```
 1, 1, 1
 1, 1, 0
 1, 1,-1
 ..
```

***Note***: The ordering matters, and 1, 0, 0, is not the same as 0, 1, 0

then, if we added another item, it would end up being..

```
 1, 1, 1, 1
 1, 1, 1, 0
 1, 1, 1,-1
 ..
```

i am getting a bit frustrated with syntax at the moment, and am not 100% sure what is possible, but have been trying to get this working with itertools.permutations, and also the concept of a 'generator' ??

So, i started off trying to get the permutations of the states..

```
itertools.permutations(states)
[(0, 1, -1), (0, -1, 1), (1, 0, -1), (1, -1, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 1, 0)]
```

and then join them up with the item list..

```
[(x,items) for x in itertools.permutations(states)]
[((0, 1, -1), ['a', 'b', 'c']), ((0, -1, 1), ['a', 'b', 'c']), ((1, 0, -1), ['a', 'b', 'c']), ((1, -1, 0), ['a', 'b', 'c']), ((-1, 0, 1), ['a', 'b', 'c']), ((-1, 1, 0), ['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```

but all this does is randomise the state list i currently have in a list.. i.e. i have no 1,1,1, or 0,0,0

Can anyone offer me some pointers.. i'm sure this must have been done before!

Comment: It seems like you want [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), not `permutations`. `(1, 1, 1)` is **not** a permutation of `(0, 1, -1)`.

Comment: Your question is not clear, apparently because you are misusing terminology. You say you want "permutations" of `state` but give the example `1,1,1` which is not a permutation. A permutation is a re-arranging of part or all of a set, *without duplication* (replacement). Your example duplicated the `1` so it is not a permutation. Please re-word your question to make it clear.

Comment: @RoryDaulton what is the correct terminology please? Combinations?!

Comment: If you want, in your group of three items, the first to be any of your `state` items, your second to be any, and your third to be any, allowing duplication/replacement, then this is a Cartesian product. Check [the product function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in itertools, or perhaps [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement). If you clarify your question we can get you a good answer. Pay attention to the order of the answers--do you want both `1,1,0` and `0,1,1`?

Comment: @RoryDaultoni have updated the query to clarify... hope that helps. Cartesian product is not what i am after.. is is definitely unique combinations... and the order certainly matters (both updated in question) - 1, 1, 0 is *not* the same as 0, 1, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

[list(zip(x, item)) for x in product(states, repeat=3)]

[[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')]]
```

Alternately, there's also [`combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

[list(zip(x, item)) for x in combinations_with_replacement(states, 3)]

[[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(0, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')],
 [(-1, 'a'), (-1, 'b'), (-1, 'c')]]
```

Comment: so, it would seem yes that the combinations_with_replacement is what i am after..  that for help in locating that... the second portion of your answer is interesting, because where is the combination of -1, 0, 0 for example?

Comment: Ok, looks like you actually want `itertools.product` - see updated answer, is that what you have in mind?

Comment: ahhh, excellent.. thank you, that is superb! i think my main failing here is terminology in being able to search the internet for what i *actually* was after. i am (kinda) pleased i wasn't really all that far off.. :)